# Difference ways of getting an element in javascript

Tags: javascript

Which is the difference between:

```
document.body
```

and

```
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
```

Comment: document.body is just a shortcut

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`document.body` is just a property on the object `document` containing a reference to the same element that `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]` gives you. That's the technical difference. The real difference is that `document.body` is easier to type... :)

Answer (score 2):

1. The `document.body` in javascript is a direct reference to the DOM element representing the `<body>` portion of the page.
2. we'll probably access the `<body>` tag a lot, we can use a shortcut (rather than using it's tagName like this: `document.getElementsByTagName("BODY").item(0)` or by assigning it an ID and using that):